# How to open new window using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to open a new window(URL is dynamic) when I click on a button.

```
function openWindow(){
     window.open('//www.google.com/','_blank');
}
```

Here my problem is , JavaScript is opening new window but Appliation name is also appending to URL. i.e it is opening new window with the below URL

http://localhost:8090/www.google.com/

I have tried all the combinations in URL but it is not working

Please do needful

Comment: Try adding the protocol for the URL. That JavaScript works fine in both Firefox and Chrome for me though.

Comment: the code you showed should open `http://www.google.com` - which will probably redirect to `https` - but  it works fine in firefox anyway

Comment: @jaromanda this code is opening new window , but as below http://localhost:8090/www.google.com/ .. I want to remove http://localhost:8090

Comment: your code does NOT do that at least in firefox, chrome, ie or edge - but the solution below should work

Comment: here's [proof](https://jsfiddle.net/mc76swm9/) that the general concept of what you are doing works ... perhaps icefaces / jsf is screwing up your code somehow - what does the code look like when you view it in the browser (view page source)

Comment: Take browser cache into account when editing JS files.

Answer (score 4):

update your javascript function like

```
function openWindow(){
     window.open('http://www.google.com/','_blank');
}
```

Comment: @Raj create a online demo which you try to implement

Answer (score 0):

**Use action listener to open new window in icefaces**

```
<ice:commandLink value="click me" actionListener="#{bean.myActionListener}"/> 
------------------------------

public void myActionListener(ActionEvent event) { 
    JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "window.open('report.iface', 'myWindow');"); 
} 
------------------------------
```

- See more at: http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/2382.page#sthash.v4eaLOKb.dpuf

Comment: hi developerbhuwan, I tried this code before writing java script. it is also not working , thats the reason I moved to java script .

Comment: and I tried below code also.. it is not working too JavaScriptRunner.runScript(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "window.open('http://www.google.com/' , '_newtab');");

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.open("http://www.google.com");`, tested works in all browsers.